# Regular Expression: search multiple string with linefeed delimited by ";"

Tags: regex

I have a string such this that described a structured data source:

```
 Header whocares;
 SampleTestPlan 2
   a b
   c d;
 Test abc;
 SampleTestPlan 3
   e f
   g h
   i l;
  Wafer 01;
  EndOfFile;
```

Every field...
... is starting with "FieldName"
... is ending with ";"
... may contain linefeed

My need is to find with regular expression the values of SampleTestPlan that's repeated twice. So...
1st value is:

```
     2
   a b
   c d
```

2nd value is

```
     3
   e f
   g h
   i l
```

I've performed several attempts with such search string:

/SampleTestPlan(.*\s)*/gm

/SampleTestPlan(.*\s)*;/gm

/SampleTestPlan(.*);/gm

but I need to understand much better how Regular Expression work as I'm definitively a newbie on them and I need to learn a lot.

Thanks in advance to anyone that may help me!

Stefano, Milan, ITALY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
(?<=\w\b)[^;]+(?=;)
```

See it working live [here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kD2pN4)!

---

***How it works:***
It matches everything that is:

- preceded by a sequence of characters: `\w+`
- followed by a `;`
- contains anything (at least one character) except a `;` (including `newline`s).

---

For example, for that input:

```
 Header whocares;
 SampleTestPlan 2
   a b
   c d;
 Test abc;
 SampleTestPlan 3
   e f
   g h
   i l;
  Wafer 01;
  EndOfFile;
```

It matches **5** times:

```
whocares
```

then:

```
     2  
   a b  
   c d
```

then:

```
abc
```

then:

```
     3  
   e f  
   g h  
   i l
```

then:

```
01
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input will be always in this well formatted like the sample, try this:

```
/SampleTestPlan(\s+\d+.*?);/sg
```

Here, `/s` modifier means `Dot matches newline characters`

You can [try this at online](http://regex101.com/r/rU4dL9).

Answer (score 0):

That would be `/SameTestPlan([^;]+)/g`. `[^abc]` means any character which is not a, b or c.